# Testing Javascript with Google Website Optimizer?

Tags: html, unit-testing, testing, google-website-optimizer

Can I test Javascript code in GWO?  For example, how would I test:

```
$('#first_name_field').watermark('First name');
```

Ideally the person who tests different content doesn't have to enter lots of javascript, only the text they want to change...  like "First name" above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can test JS code in a MVT. You obviously can for a A/B test.

For the MVT case just wrap the GWO section code around html the `script` tags you want to test (you may need to add some).